# How to use responsive-loader and jest?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, responsive-loader

While using [`responsive-loader`](https://github.com/dazuaz/responsive-loader), I get all my unit test failing in Jest during the import of an image with format webp: `?format=web`:

```
Cannot find module '../images/11_1920-xl.jpg?format=webp' from 'src/Home.js';
```

How can I use both jest and responsive-loader webp?

Answer (score 0):

I did overcome the issue by adding in my jest configuration:

```json
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png)\\?format=webp$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/jpgPngMock.js"},
    "transformIgnorePatterns":[
      "<rootDir>/__mocks__/jpgPngMock.js"
    ]
}
```

and within `__mocks__/jpgPngMock.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  src: '',
  srcSet: '',
  width: 1,
  height: 1,
};
```